# Support broadcast events from any Music player android

Tags: android, android-music-player, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an application which should do an action whenever a user starts or stops music player in android. I researched on it and found a way to do. But it only receives events from only default music player. Other streaming player like Rdio, last.fm were left behind.

The code i used

Manifest.xml

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MediaStateReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.music.playstatechanged" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MediaStateReceiver.java

```
public class MediaStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    LogUtil.print("broadcast event recieved " + intent.getAction());
    if(intent.hasExtra("playing")) {
        Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(context, MusicStateChangeService.class);
        mediaIntent.putExtra("MUSIC_STATE", true);
        mediaIntent.putExtra("playing",intent.getBooleanExtra("playing",false));
        context.startService(mediaIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

Is there any way to receive broadcast events from any music player.?